# Doubts about complex conjugate theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

This theorem states that a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients has one roots in complex then other is its complex conjugate. Therefore any real number which is root of $p(x)$ can be written as $a+i0$ therefore $a-i0$ is also a root so it means it has the same root twice...

But it's not true in general... So I think I made a misunderstanding. Please help me to find out.

Comment: No, if $a$ is a real root, then $\bar a = a$, so the only thing you know is that your polynomial has the root $a$, not that it has it twice. I mean, you don't obtain extra information about the roots of your polynomial.

Comment: So the theorem says that if z satisfy the equation then it's conjugate too...Am I right

Comment: Yes, it is. If $p(z)=0$, then $p(\bar z)=0$. If $z$ is real, you are actually saying that $p(z)=0$ implies $p(z)=0$.

Comment: It does not imply that a real root must have multiplicity two. It just says that if $p(z) = 0$ then $p(\overline{z}) = 0$. If $z$ is real, it says nothing, since $z = \overline{z}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @flytothesurface

Comment: It just says that if $z$ is a root, then $\bar{z}$ is a root. It says nothing about multiplicity. This is obviously trivial if $z$ is real.

Comment: It says: if 2 is a root then 2 is a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proof: Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a zero of the polynomial
$$f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \ldots + a_1x +a_0$$
where all $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $z$ is a zero of $f(x)$, we have that
$$0 = f(z)$$.
Consider the conjugate of $z$, denoted by $\overline{z}$, then we have that
$$f(\overline{z}) = a_n\overline{z}^n + a_{n-1}\overline{z}^{n-1}+ \ldots + a_1\overline{z} +a_0.$$
Note that we have the following properties:
$$\overline{z}^n = \overline{z} \cdot \overline{z} \cdot \ldots \cdot \overline{z} = \overline{z \cdot z \cdot \ldots \cdot z} = \overline{z^n}$$
and for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\lambda \overline{z} = \overline{\lambda \cdot z}$$
since $\overline{\lambda} = \lambda$. Moreover $\overline{z_1 + z_2} = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}$.
This shows that 
$$a_n\overline{z}^n + a_{n-1}\overline{z}^{n-1}+ \ldots + a_1\overline{z} +a_0 = \overline{a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+ \ldots + a_1z +a_0} = \overline{0} = 0.$$

Note that this proof really needs that the $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, since we could only take the previous steps because $\overline{a_i} = a_i$ for $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

As a counterexample for a polynomial which has complex coefficients: consider
$$p(z) = (z - i)(z + 3i) = z^2 + 2iz +3,$$ 
which has complex coefficients and although $i$ is a zero, $-i$ is not.